# Anima and Reach Issues

Tags: reactjs

I hired someone to do a UX design for my website. I have the designs in Figma. I've never used Figma before. I just tried out Anima. I bought the $50.00 a month plan. I wanted to see how it could help me as a developer. It has this weird white spot on the website that shouldn't be there.
Any idea how I can remove that?

Also I am trying to switch the anima webpage into Godaddy. I don't know how to do this.

Also does anyone know how I can build my website from scratch after I download the figma files?

What should I do?

I tried to get the site from anima working on godaddy but i'm not sure of what to do.